# change variables with setState in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an issue with setState() in Flutter. I just write a simple program that have a container and a button , the color of container is global variable mycolor and i change it in  on_pressed function of button with setState but its doesn't change.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: _Home(),));

Color bgColor = Colors.red;


class _Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  __HomeState createState() => __HomeState();
}

class __HomeState extends State<_Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        //First Widget
        Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          color: bgColor,
        ),
        //Second Widget
        SecondWidget()
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SecondWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondWidgetState createState() => _SecondWidgetState();
}

class _SecondWidgetState extends State<SecondWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Change color"),
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
         bgColor = Colors.green; 
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZUfa.png)

Comment: I was looking for a simple code sample using two statefulWidgets this was perfect. Helped me code something simple and enough for the needs of the simple logic. No need to use a library or coding pattern with the answers below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `setState` in `_SecondWidgetState` not in `__HomeState`, so only `SecondWidget` redraws and it does not depend on `bgColor`.
What you can do here: the easiest option would be to pass a callback function from `__HomeState` to `SecondWidget`, which will call `setState` inside `__HomeState`.
Example code:

```dart
class __HomeState extends State<_Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        //First Widget
        Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          color: bgColor,
        ),
        //Second Widget
        SecondWidget(callSetState);
      ],
    );
  }

  void callSetState() {
    setState((){}); // it can be called without parameters. It will redraw based on changes done in _SecondWidgetState
  }
}

class SecondWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final Function onClick;

  SecondWidget(this.onClick);

  @override
  _SecondWidgetState createState() => _SecondWidgetState();
}

class _SecondWidgetState extends State<SecondWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Change color"),
      onPressed: (){
        bgColor = Colors.green; 
        widget.onClick();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is simple solution for two widgets, but you will have problems if you will try to manage state on larger scale. I recommend you to read articles about state management in flutter. [This one](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) can be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass that variable to your sibling widget `SecondWidget()`.

First you declare it on your `SecondWidget` like this:

```
class SecondWidget extends StatefulWidget {

Color backgroundColor;

SecondWidget({Key key, @required this.backgroundColor}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondWidgetState createState() => _SecondWidgetState();
}
```

You need to pass that color from `_HomeState` to `SecondWidget`, you do it like this:

```
class __HomeState extends State<_Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        //First Widget
        Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          color: bgColor,
        ),
        //Second Widget
        SecondWidget(backgroundColor: bgColor) // Here you pass that color
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Then on your `SecondWidgetState`, you can update your other widget color using `setState()`, like this:

```
setState(() {
 widget.backgroundColor = Colors.blue;
});
```

Hope this helps fix your issue.